# Rails - redirect_to can't find route if it's wrapped with constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have route like this wrapped by constraint.

```
constraints DomainConstraint.new('admin.example.com') do
  get '/admin/:page', to: 'admin#browse', as: :admin_index
end

constraints DomainConstraint.new('client.example.com') do
  get '/:page', to: 'client#index', as: :client_index
end
```

Now, When I want to redirect request from `admin.example.com` controller to `client` controller via:

```
def some_page
  redirect_to action: :client_index, 
end
```

It says:

```
No route matches
```

I believe this happens because I wrapped routes with constraint. How can i redirect admin to client using `constraints`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your code is not working because `action` params takes the name of action on the same controller if you don't specify the controller name.

Change your code from

```
def some_page
   redirect_to action: :client_index, 
end
```

To

```
def some_page
   redirect_to controller: 'client', action: :index 
end
```

More info on `redirect_to` [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to)